# Galaxy S2 no USB Conenction after firmware update

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb, device-firmware

I just got an automatic firmware update for my Galaxy S2

```
Android 2.3.6
I9100GXXKL4
Kernel 2.6.35.7 dpi@DELL164 #2
GINGERBREAD.XXLB1
```

Now the USB connection does not work anymore and I cannot continue developing using eclipse. Where can I find new drivers for the new version? Already checked samsung.com but did not find anything!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a driver issue.

Please try the following-

> 1. Unplug the USB cable from your phone.
> 2. On the phone, dial the following number:   ***#7284#**

Once the last # is hit, the **PhoneUtil** application should be launched.

> Choose **USB -> Modem** and then **USB -> PDA mode**.

The good mode should be PDA. Even if the mode is PDA, switch to Modem and then back to PDA!!!

> Now Plug the USB cable back in your phone/PC and check if it works.

(I had the same problem on my Samsung Galaxy 3, and I resolved it like this)

Comment: Thanks so much. Sameer Sharma. I've got the same problem on my GalaxyS2, 2.3.6 version of Android. "Android 2.3.6
I9100GXXKL4
Kernel 2.6.35.7 dpi@DELL164 #2
GINGERBREAD.XXLB1" It works.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem:

1. Uninstall Kies and USB drivers
2. Restart PC
3. Install Kies
4. Restart PC
5. Finally, connect phone to PC (USB debugging off) then let Windows automatically install drivers for the phone